# Canvas zoom with stroke and text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**I want zoom images, lines, and text drawn on a `canvas`**

- Click `plus` button > zoom in
- Click `minus` button > zoom out

I tried scale but only the image got bigger.

*test.html*

```html
<canvas id="img"></canvas>

<input type="button" id="plus" value="plus">
<input type="button" id="minus" value="minus">

<script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('img');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = 'test.PNG';
        img.onload = function() {
            canvas.height = img.height;
            canvas.width = img.width;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
            ctx.strokeRect(28, 26, 50, 50);

            ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
            ctx.font="15px Verdana";
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fillText("TEXT", 28, 25 + 50 + 5);
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.scale(2,2);
            ctx.restore();
        };
</script>

<script>
        const plus = document.getElementById('plus');
        const minus = document.getElementById('minus');
</script>
```

[image: img]

Comment: scale before drawing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - as Kaiido implied in his comment - that the `scale()` method doesn't affect anything thas has been drawn onto the canvas prior the call to scale.

If you really want a context.scale driven zoom function you will have to redraw anything **after** calling scale.

Here's an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('img');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function zoomIn() {
  myScale = myScale < 2.5 ? myScale += 0.5 : 2.5;
  draw();
}

function zoomOut() {
  myScale = myScale > 0.5 ? myScale -= 0.5 : 0.5;
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2 - canvas.width / 2 * myScale, canvas.height / 2 - canvas.height / 2 * myScale);
  ctx.scale(myScale, myScale);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.strokeRect(28, 26, 50, 50);

  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.font = "15px Verdana";
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillText("TEXT", 28, 25 + 50 + 5);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
}
var img = new Image();
var myScale = 1;

img.onload = function() {
  canvas.height = img.height;
  canvas.width = img.width;
  draw();

};
img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300';

const plus = document.getElementById('plus');
const minus = document.getElementById('minus');
plus.addEventListener("click", zoomIn);
minus.addEventListener("click", zoomOut);
```

```html
<canvas id="img"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="plus" value="plus">
<input type="button" id="minus" value="minus">
```